# Changing build for external testers, but not internal

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, testflight

I have two different builds (v. 1 and v. 2). Both internal and external testers are currently running on v. 2. I now want to revert the external testers to v. 1, whilst still keeping internal testers on v. 2.

When setting v. 1 to my external testers, I get prompted with the question: *"Are you sure you want to test iOS version 1.0? Your current iOS version 2.0 will no longer be made available to your testers."*

**Does this mean that my internal testers also will get reverted to version 1.0?**

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you upload a new binary, it will be automatically make available for Internal Testers. I believe, you should have option to choose this for external but not for internals.

Comment: Yes, that's my understanding as well. But in this case I want to revert from 2.0 to 1.0 for external testers without affecting the internal testers.

Comment: Is 1.0 is still visible inside build section for external testers ?

Comment: Yes. 1.0 & 2.0 is visible for external testers. Internal testers only see 2.0.

Answer (score 0):

I found out the answer: it is possible to revert back to 1.0 only for external testers.